# Lose some values using getStringSet and putStringSet

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I found out that some values had been stored to `Set` got lost after restarting the application. Why? Is this an Android API bug? Somebody advised to store strings in a database. I haven't tested it yet, but I think this advice is a solution of the problem. What about `getStringSet` and `putStringSet`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my understanding, it's a bug. The problem is when you try to store a set, Android compares the modified set that you are trying to save with the current one stored in the SharedPreferences. And when they are the same object (having the same reference), the new one is ignored.

A work around is to create a new copy of the set before storing it.

[Here](http://androiddev.orkitra.com/?p=7297) is the details and the issue is submitted at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=27801.

Comment: Thank you. But I preffer a database with a single table contains `NOT NULL UNIQUE TEXT` for strings.

Answer (score 4):

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.remove(key);
editor.commit();
editor.putStringSet(key, value);
editor.commit();

Comment: Try expounding on this answer a little more. Code is nice, but explanations are better for all future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem using SharedPreferences. There seems to be a bug in the Android API. I've made a small post on it [here](http://bon-app-etit.blogspot.be/2013/08/android-bug-stringset-in.html)

The easiest way for me was to remove it, commit it, then put it and commit it again